# How to make page content created by ckeditor responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor, responsive

I'm using Ckeditor to create content for posts and pages. I wonder how to make the content responsive(not to purchase some ckeditor bootstrap plugins)?

There are two possible way that come to my mind:
1. Parse the raw html code generated by ckeditor and add bootstrap classes to corresponding html tags (e.g. img-responsive etc) before storing the data in database.
2. Add media queries in css files.

I don't know which is the better way and how to implement each of them. I appreciate your suggestions! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to dive into your second option: CSS media queries. It will allow you a greater scope of customization and ultimately benefit your development skills. Media queries are brilliant to know how to use, and aren't too difficult if you already have an understanding of using CSS selectors and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ckeditor yourself (as opposed to your users creating content) then you can use 'Source Mode' plugin to edit the raw html and add the bootstrap classes you need.
This is based on the assumption that bootstrap is already loaded on to any pages which will display the ckeditor content or the script is included through 'Source Mode'.
http://ckeditor.com/addon/sourcearea

Answer (score 0):

For mine I wrapped all my ckeditor contents into a div with class .note-content and set the max-width of media located in the div.

```
.note-content
{
  img, iframe {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
  }
}
```